# Load dictionary into multiple dictionaries using marshmallow schema

Tags: python, dictionary, marshmallow

I want to do something like this:

I have a `dict`:

```
x = {
     'D': 'abc',
     'E': 'def',
     'F': 'asd',
     'G': 'gef'
}
```

I want the marshmallow schema to convert it into `dict` that looks something like:

```
y = {
   'var1': {
       'D': 'abc',
       'E': 'def',
       'F': 'asd'
   },
   'var2': {
       'G': 'gef'
   }
}
```

UPDATE: consider that i have another dict that defines where the keys should be present

```
s = {
       'var1': ['D', 'E', 'F', 'I'],
       'var2': ['G', 'A']
   }
```

I am unable to figure out the schema to make this work.

Comment: I don't get why `D'`, `'E'` and `'F'` should here belong to `'var1'` and `'G'` to `'var2'`. Based on what do you decide where to put these?

Comment: >> i am unable to figure the schema to make this work. Yes, me neither)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: i have updated the question

Comment: @DragonSlayer: can the "schema" cascade? or is it only a *single* level?

Comment: there is no schema, you just take items from one dictionary and split into more dictionaries according to settings provided in other file.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: it can cascade.

Comment: @Drako: i know that it could be done by splitting the dictionary. I thought schema could help make the actual code cleaner.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: can this be done..or should i simply split the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Not officially, no. This is a documented bug/missing feature: https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/940.

However, there are very simple workarounds. Here is mine (which is also posted in that thread):

```py
from marshmallow import fields

class SelfNested(fields.Nested):
    def get_value(self, obj, attr, accessor=None, default=missing):
        return obj
```

You can now use this `SelfNested` class as though it is a regular `Nested`, but it will let you access parent fields.

So for your example, you might do this:

```py
from marshmallow import fields
from marshmallow.schema import Schema

class Var1Schema(Schema):
    D = fields.String()
    E = fields.String()
    F = fields.String()

class Var2Schema(Schema):
    G = fields.String()

class MySchema(Schema):
    var1 = SelfNested(Var1Schema())
    var2 = SelfNested(Var2Schema())
```